# Figuring out how to remove pieces of a string

Tags: python, replace

I need to replace the spaces in a given sentence without replacing the spaces in the first two words, is there a way to do that in python?

Comment: provide sample data and desired output , plus what you have tried

Answer (score 0):

If you post an example it would be easier to answer but here's a guess at what you're asking for

```python
# Slicing method
s = "Word one Word two rest of sentence"
s = s[:17] + s[17:].replace(' ', '_')
# result: 'Word one Word two_rest_of_sentence'
```

Comment: is there a way without slicing, say if i have the sentence "jimmy does laundry cooks cleans." how do I remove the first 2 words so that I can use replace on laundry and cooks to change it to laundry, cooks, Thanks so much